# List or table within a list

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I searched everywhere but couldn't find a definite answer: Is it possible to create a *JasperReport's* report containing a *List that contains another List (or table) inside it*? If yes, how can I pass parameters to the inside list?

I tried implementing this in *iReport* and received the following exception:

```
Error filling print... null 
Setting up the file resolver...  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.FillTableFactory.cloneFillComponent(FillTableFactory.java:46)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.<init>(JRFillComponentElement.java:77)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.createClone(JRFillComponentElement.java:187)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementGroup.<init>(JRFillElementGroup.java:105)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.<init>(JRFillElementContainer.java:100)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.FillListContents.<init>(FillListContents.java:58)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.FillListContents.createClone(FillListContents.java:97)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.HorizontalFillList.getContents(HorizontalFillList.java:308)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.HorizontalFillList.prepare(HorizontalFillList.java:142)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:129)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:331)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.FillListContents.prepare(FillListContents.java:86)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.VerticalFillList.fillContents(VerticalFillList.java:153)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.VerticalFillList.prepare(VerticalFillList.java:102)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:129)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:331)     
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:379)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:353)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2046)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      a
t org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered this error too. Later I found that the method `net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.FillTableFactory.cloneFillComponent` is actually not implemented until 6.0.0. So I replaced the old Jasperreport Library with 6.0.0 and the problem is solved.

Comment: I can't test it right now so I'm not sure if you are right in order to accept the answer. However if this answer gets any other upvotes I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: I have a table created A and one of the column of A containns another table B. but B is not coming in the Final report. How to pass dataset to inner table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the notion of "Subdataset" to be included as a table for instance in the Details band.
C.f. official IReport documentation (ireport-ultimate-guide.pdf) on their website.

Comment: I really can't understand - can you elaborate a little more ? Let's say I have a detail band in which I want to add a list and inside that list I want to add a table - so the number of tables that will be render would be the number the times the detail will be rendered multipled by the times each list will be rendered ! Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes! The Detail band is already the first list so to say. Every content in the Detail band is rendered once per record in your (main-) report query. If you add a table into this band having its own sub-query or sub-dataset you will end up with as many tables as your (main) report query return records. Each table will have as many rows (sub-dataset records) as the sub-query returns for a given (main-) record.

Comment: Hello ! I didn't make myself clear i guess: I want to render a table and *inside* each one of the cells of that table render *another* table (and possibly, inside the cells of the second table render *another* one). Can this be done ? I think not but I ask to be positive.